# live monitorng query status from impala shell

Tags: hadoop, impala

I have a large impala query that runs for over 8 hours.

The output is printed on the ssh screen which is piped to a file and processed into a csv...

In this long time while the query runs, is there any way for me to check the status from another terminal window ?

Is there any way to get the query number to do this ?

Im completly new to impala.. couldnt try much

Comment: yes, you can monitor the SQL execution through cloudera navigator. Also cloudera admin can tell you how you can set alert if SQL fails/going more than 8 hrs . But i would say, do not create a sql that takes 8 hour to process, Break into small parts - easy to manage and execute.

Comment: YARN API has status of all pending jobs

Comment: hello @KoushikRoy thank you for that.. is there any way to do it from impala-shell I only have access to that?

Comment: No, you need access to YARN (which is what Cloudera Manager reads). The impala shell doesn't monitor queries, only submits

Comment: That is sad! Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: you can check with CDH admin, its just acccess thing - and they can give you read only access as well to just monitor.